# Angular UI: field entered in Modal is undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please run this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RtzAvkL3wCVFYkfhyv9D?p=preview), if you enter a value in the modal and then click on show value, the value is undefined in $scope, how to get the value?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="openModal()" value="Open Modal">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
        </div>
        <form name="myForm" novalidate>
            Enter a value <input type="text" ng-model="someField" />
                </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button ng-click="showValue()">Show value</button>
        </div>
   </script>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

  $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope
        });
  };

  $scope.showValue = function() {
      alert('value entered=' + $scope.someField);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this because the `scope` of the modal is isolated.  Even though you pass the `$scope` to modal.  It still does not use the same `$scope`.

**For your example the following would work.**

Update the modal template:

```
<button ng-click="showValue(someField)">Show value</button>
```

Update your controller showValue method as follows:

```
 $scope.showValue = function(theValue) {
      $scope.someField = theValue;
      alert('value entered=' + $scope.someField);
  };
```

Really though the best way to use the modal is to use the modal instance created by the open method to track the `close` and `dismiss` events and handle the result that way.  Take a look at the example on on the `ui-modal` section of the [ui-bootstrap documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I understand that the way to use the modal is as documented, but it forces me to replicate all the fields in the modal and in the main controllers, in addition to handle them via resolve action. It's much easier to just define the fields as `ng-model` and use them.

Comment: @ps0604 you should consider setting up a factory that models the fields for you and returns a `JSON` object that you can use for your required fields and methods you need for that object.  Then you can just use factory value in both controllers easily by just setting `$scope.myObj = myFactory();`